# MS Project 2010: Can I define an "overhead" task?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I have an "overhead" task for tracking work related to administration of a project. As such, the project requires about 5 hours of administrative overhead work per week of its existence.

How can I define such a task that will always be equivalent to 5 hours of work per week for the life of the project?

For example, if my project schedule gets lengthened because another task took longer to complete, I want this 'overhead' task to also lengthen so that for every week that the project is lengthened, an additional 5 hours are included in the work.

Any advise is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This type of work package is called "level of effort."  You put a finish finish constraint with the milestone or work package that represents the lengthened project.  This will keep pushing the effort's finish date out.  However, you do not "add" the additional five hours per week.  Your planned value stays the same and is baselined.  So, for example, if the total hours for your project was planned to be 100 hours, it remains 100 hours.  However, your actual hours continue to climb producing an unfavorable variance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "hammock" task that will span the length of the project and its finish will adjust with the linked task.

See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141733/en-us

If you must account for the approximate 5 hours per week, assign the Project Manager at 12.5% to the task to generate the appropriate work estimate.

However, do you truly need to get to that level of detail within the Project plan?  Are you able to track to that level of detail?  Unless your organization is tracking to that level and requires the documentation of that task - I would omit it and simply set the Project Manager's max units lower to account for the overhead work.